# cx_oracle python and select Like %variable%

Tags: python, oracle, cursor, cx-oracle, execute

I'm trying  to execute a query based on "tempo" variable,using %tempo%
none of the solution that I found here help my problem

```
import cx_oracle
query="""SELECT description, local, point, date  
           FROM tbl_ext_tempo 
          WHERE point like '%' || :0 || '%' 
            AND ROWNUM < 8 
          ORDER BY date DESC
       """
cursor.execute(query, tempo)
```

Exception Value:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Comment: What's the data type of the `point` column, and how do you declare the `tempo` variable witihn the code ? Btw, `date` cannot be a column name as being a reserved keyword, perhaps it might be `"date"`.

Comment: point is varchar, tempo is string, the column data name is dt_cri,your right.I've just changed. I'm able to do the query from sql developer and from view, the problem start when i'm want touse a variable string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a list(`lst`), and append the current string to it as formatted

```
lst = []
tempo = 'someValue'
query="""
         SELECT description, local, point, "date"
           FROM tbl_ext_tempo
          WHERE point LIKE :0          
            AND ROWNUM < 8
          ORDER BY "date" DESC
       """   
lst.append('%{}%'.format(tempo))
cursor.execute(query,(lst))
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

`date` cannot be a column name as being a reserved keyword, perhaps it might be `"date"` as quoted.

Comment: You're welcome @Jorge Marques , nice to help.